# add more property in aspnet_profile

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership

i have application that uses .net membership,it has some properties now i want to add more properties, its not throwing error but when i check in the aspnet_profile table the new properties i added doesnot exist. What i am doing wrong?

my code is also here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1629200.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly accessing the Profile property of HttpContext.Current, have you tried:

```
Dim profile As ProfileCommon = Profile.GetProfile(username)
```